# SAPUI5 / CustomTile - slide by one tile

Tags: json, sapui5

I'm developing an SAP-ui5 XML view. In that view I created dynamic custom tiles using the `CustomTile` tag,  as demonstrated in this image:

[image]

```
    <TileContainer
        id="container"
        height="400px"        
        tileDelete="handleTileDelete"
        tiles="{/TileCollection}">
        <tiles>             
           <CustomTile id="ct1">
              <content>               
                    <VBox>                                             
                       <Toolbar class="backcolor" design="Transparent">                                                                          
                         <Text class="sapMHeader" text="Dynamic content" />                           
                       </Toolbar>                                                 
                       <Button type="{infoState}" text="Button"
                          icon="sap-icon://approvals"                              
                          ariaDescribedBy="defaultButtonDescription genericButtonDescription">
                       </Button>                          
                    </VBox>
              </content>
           </CustomTile> 
        </tiles>
     </TileContainer>
```

Currently, clicking on the navigate button slides three tiles per click. I want to get it to slide only one tile per click. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please show your code so people can find the problem in it.

Comment: Strongly Recommend to use the default handler itself since it handles based on the space available for TileContainer.

Comment: @SunilBN If possible can you send some code samples. So that it will easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The `TileContainer` control is responsive meaning how many tiles you see totally depends on the available screen space and nothing else. The scroll-buttons act as an overflow and slide a complete 'page' just as a `Carousel` would do. There is no way of changing this behavior via existing API.

If you really want to adapt this behavior `TileContainer.prototype.scrollLeft` and `TileContainer.prototype.scrollRight` are probably a good starting point.

BR
Chris